# Run a python script when connected to internet

Tags: linux

I have a simple python script `hello.py` and a `hello.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -c "from hello import hello; hello()"
```

(`hello.py` is in PYTHONPATH)

made it executeable and placed in the `if-up.d` directory. Being in the directory and running `./hello.sh` it works as it should. But disconnecting and re-connecting does not trigger the script.

Even it the script is just `echo "hello">>out.txt` it still doesn't get executed. My user is owner of the script (running ubuntu 20.04)

Any idea?

Comment: The script works if I run it - but it does not seem like it is triggered on connection

Comment: Even it the script is just 'echo "hello">>out.txt' it still doesn't get executed

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it as you mentioned the variables (it is included now).

Comment: Atm, via wireless. I am running ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below with setting the correct  interface name :

```
 #!/bin/sh 
    if [ "$IFACE" = <interface-name> ]; then 
        python <path_to_your_script>.py
    fi
```

Don't forget to make it **executable** :

```
sudo chmod +x <path_to_your_script>.sh
```

Also if your interface is managed by NetworkManager this wil not work.

Comment: I have tried that (setting <interface-name> as "wlan0") but it still does not seem to work

Comment: Okay your system is based on systemd ? Coul you also check if you are running NetworkManager ?

Comment: I have also tried placing in it `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher` but w/o any luck. I am rather new to Linux btw

Comment: what is the output of systemctl status network and systemctl status NetworkManager ?